# iOS 13 push-notifications delegate methods are not called

Tags: push-notification, ios13

In my existing applications I am not able to receive delegate methods:

- Xcode 11 & iOS 12.3.1  - Working
- Xcode 11 & iOS 13  - Not Working

Comment: I don't think you need the objective-c tag here since it's happening in Swift projects as well.
Happens with a demo app I put together. 
Using Xcode 11 and a device with iOS 12 or lower installed, this delegate method gets called:

```func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)``` 

Running same code on an iOS 13 device it doesn't get called.

Comment: @ArnoldPlakolli I am having VoIP service in Project so it seems like it's only called when I disable VoIP services.

Comment: I didn't try to disable VoIP notifications. Maybe it really works in that case. In any case, I'm fixing the problem for now by restarting device when this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes building the code base with XCode 11 and iOS 13 seemed to fix this for me.

- built app with Xcode 10 + iOS 12.
- installed on iOS12
- installed on iOS13.0
- send push
- only appearing on iOS12
- Rebuilt the app with XCode 11 and iOS 13.0
- Send push
- appears on iOS 12.4 + iOS 13.0

Answer (score 1):

Restarting device seems to fix it. Happened a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

I Changed the network from wifi to cellular data and it started working again. I even tested it with the old wifi network & it works

Also, if you used your internet connection in the MAC to share using USB. Turn it off & connect your IPhone with a normal wifi or mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

So I created IPA from XCODE 10 and it's working fine in even iOS 13.